# How regex works in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I wanted to know how does having a very strict rule impact the performance of regex in c#.

e.g if I expect a string (which I'll read from somewhere) to contain [a-zA-z0-9] only, but at the same time I am sure, that the one giving me the string will always return a string which has this rule. So, in this case will using just '.' rather than a-zA-Z0-9 have any performance impact or not?

How do these two work differently?

Comment: If you want to know which of two things is faster, try it both ways and measure the result, and then you'll know.

Comment: How does it go Eric? Race the horses? :)

Comment: @EricLippert - Next question: In C# how do I measure the performance of a regex?

Comment: Check this link out http://ayende.com/blog/2930/regex-vs-string-indexof. There's a good example which compares IndexOf, with regex.

Comment: You contradict yourself, if your considering testing for `.` (and why not `.length==0`?) then you cant be that sure the input conforms to what you expect. Have you observed `[a-zA-z0-9]` causing performance problems?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Performance is always in the context of something that *affects a user*. If it doesn't affect a user then why would you care?  So one way would be to find a user, show them the performance both ways, and ask them if performance is acceptable in one case but not in the other. Use the user as your measurement device, since their satisfaction is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

> if I expect a string (which I'll read from somewhere) to contain [a-zA-z0-9] only, but at the same time I am sure, that the one giving me the string will always return a string which has this rule.

You cannot be sure of this. You know what it means to [assume](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Assume). Your code can be used by others, your program can be fed input by others. Write defensive code. Always. No excuses.

> So, in this case will using just '.' rather than a-zA-Z0-9 have any performance impact or not?

Disregarding above statement, if you're sure the input will match your expectations, you don't have to verify whether they do. You must have other constraints, like "the string will have a length of X or greater", which you can simply by checking `string.Length` and methods like [`String.INOWS()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).